# How to recover the original function from a fitting?

Tags: fitting

Suppose I have an original function as follows
fun[x_] := 6*Exp[-4 x^2];

which has the following plot

```
Plot[fun[x], {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]
Then I produce a dataset from it in far x's (the reason for choosing the far x's is that I want to do a cross-check about asymptotic behavior of my original function in a real case)

```
vals = Table[{x, fun[x]}, {x, 2, 5, 5/10000}];
```

when I do the fitting

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[vals, {a1*Exp[-b1*(x)^2]}, {a1, b1}, x, 
  Method -> NMinimize];
fit//Normal
(*0.54381860615 E^(-3.42096742465 x^2)*)
```

I get the above result where exponent is close to original one (namely 4) but the coefficient is so far with respect to original one (6). However the more shift I do, the better coefficient is obtained. According to Taylor theorem if we have enough points of a function and its derivatives we must recover the original function, so why I can't recover the original function by enough points? any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

fun[x_] := 6*Exp[-4 x^2]

vals = Table[{x, fun[x]}, {x, 2, 5, 1/20}];
```

With data that is expected to be exponential, work with the log of the data.

```
vals2 = {#[[1]], Log[#[[2]]]} & /@ vals;

f = Exp[a1 - b1*x^2] /. 
   NonlinearModelFit[vals2, {a1 - b1*x^2, b1 > 0}, {a1, b1}, x, 
     Method -> "NMinimize"]["BestFitParameters"] // Quiet

(* E^(1.79176 - 4. x^2) *)
```

The constant factor is

```
E^(Log[f /. x -> 0])

(* 5.99999 *)
```

Comment: Thanks but why do you use `Exp[a1 - b1*x^2]` for fitting? finally you just obtained factor 6 and not the original function, `6*Exp[-4 x^2]` ?

Comment: Since I took the `Log` of the data in order to get a better fit, the parameters returned are for `Exp[a1-b1*x^2]`. The result obtained is **`E^(1.79176 - 4.*x^2)`**. This is equivalent to `E^(1.79176) * E^(-4.*x^2)`. The initial factor `E^(1.79176) ` is equivalent to `5.99999` so the result is equivalent to `5.99999 E^(-4.0*x^2)`.  The last part was just showing you that the constant factor was `5.99999` or about `6`

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed comment.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you consult statistician or someone who knows numerical analysis if these analyses/concerns are for work rather than a hobby.

The "data" generated from the formula is without error (other than numerical precision) and doesn't even require a regression function or even more than 2 data points.  Here's why I say that:

```
(* Define the function *)
fun[x_] := 6*Exp[-4 x^2]

(* Now generate values at 2 values of x *)
x1=2;
x2=5;

(* Now determine the coefficients in the function from the 2 points *)
Solve[{a Exp[-b x1^2] == fun[x1], a Exp[-b x2 ^2] == fun[x2]}, {a, b}, Reals]
(* {{a -> 6, b -> 4}} *)
```

This also works for larger values of $x$ (which I think you are interested in larger values as opposed to what "asymptotic" means) as long as you rationalize the values of $x$:

```
x1 = Rationalize[20.7, 0];
x2 = Rationalize[50.8, 0];
Solve[{a Exp[-b x1^2] == fun[x1], a Exp[-b x2 ^2] == fun[x2]}, {a, b}, Reals]
(* {{a -> 6, b -> 4}} *)
```

For this particular function you can avoid the need to rationalize if you take the log of the function:

```
x1 = 20.7;
x2 = 50.8;
Solve[{Log[a] - b x1^2 == Log[6] - 4 x1^2, Log[a] - b x2 ^2 == Log[6] - 4 x2^2}, {a, b}, Reals]
(* {{a -> 6., b -> 4.}} *)
```